# Use AWS Java SDK to read text file from S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-java-sdk

Im trying to read a text file from AWS S3 object store (and then send it via http to a client). I have AWS CLI command which copies the file locally, but how can I do that via the SDK? I want to read the contents as string and avoid saving as a file and then read it back.

In CLI, I create a profile with keys (one time only):

```
aws configure --profile cloudian
```

Which then asks for questions like `AWS Access Key ID [None]:` and such. And then I need to run this command to retrieve the file:

```
aws --profile=cloudian --endpoint-url=https://s3-abc.abcstore.abc.net s3 cp s3://abc-store/STORE1/abc2/ABC/test_08.txt test.txt
```

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3/CopyObject.java This is exact example, and you have to keep the key and secret on your user profile or in property file.

Comment: But this one asks a bucket name. I have an endpoint, plus need to copy it locally.

Answer (score 1):

For Reading S3 Object using SDK :

```
String s3Key ="";
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
s3Key = URLDecoder.decode("s3Key", "UTF-8");
String s3BuckerName="Your Bucket Name";
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3BuckerName, s3Key));
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent();
```

You can get the content with the above code.
And I dint get second part of your question, do you wanna send this data somewhere?